# How to make a contact form work in php?

Tags: php, html

I want to make a contact form in php. All my inputs didn't get submit. I am not sure what did I do wrong.

I really appreciate to whoever that can help me on this.

**Form in HTML**
[image: HTML]

**Form View** 
[image: View]

**When I submit - this is what I see. Nothing got** `submit` :(
[image: Sent]

Comment: Your form tag does not have `method` attribute. By default it is GET, but in the script you are trying to get data from POST method.

Comment: Reason not to paste code:____________________?

Comment: Stack overflow, won't let me post it - due to more code than explanation. Plus, with image, reader(s) can see code in syntax highlighting. I think it's great.

Comment: @Cheery : You're right.

Comment: You've got what, 60 lines of code. I've seen lower rep'd people post a lot more than that. How are we to know that your heredoc doesn't contain spaces where there shouldn't be?

Answer (score 2):

Your form is submitted via `$_GET` and you are using `$_POST` to fetch them.

You need to add this to your form tag:

```
method="post"
```

By default your form will be submitted via `$_GET`. That's why you couldn't fetch things.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the method `post` in your form.

By the way, you need to specify in your .php if you receive the data as a GET or POST